# How can I reverse lookup a localized string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

I am interested in finding the localized string key for a given text on the screen.

Is this possible ?

For instance in a contrived example:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"The key for this label",nil);

// at runtime

UILabel *theLabel = ... // get the label
NSString *text = theLabel.text; 
NSLog(@"%@",text); // prints "Foo bar"

// now I want to get the key:

NSString *localizedKey = ???? NSLocalizedStringReverseLookup(text) 
NSLog(@"%@",localizedKey); // should print "The key for this label"
```

Comment: does my answer help? is that an option for you?

Comment: You would do this by writing code. However, I would think that the approach is totally misguided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in some cases as nburk said, but you cannot do it in others:

- It is possible that different keys refers to the same string. You cannot find out, which key was the original one.
- Strings on screens can contain data pasted into the string via `%…`. You will not find the string then.

Why do you want to do this?

Comment: ah true... forgot about the variables in localized string. well, this _could_ still be implemented but this would indeed required a much more sophisticated implementation and something like a fuzzy search instead of a concrete lookup

Comment: about having different keys referring to the same string, this can easily be avoided by just not doing so (after all, key-value systems are based on the assumption of not having multiple keys for the same value). your point however is totally valid and it's the responsibility of the developer to make sure the k/v-mechanism is used correctly

Comment: I have an unusual case where I need my SDK integrated to a 3rd party app and need the underlying text of the labels

Comment: @nburk since we are talking about *reverse* lookup, the issue arises from having multiple *keys* having the same *value* - which is **perfectly valid** but problematic for *reverse* lookup. For this reason I don't believe what the OP wants to do is a good idea.

Comment: @AvnerBarr Of course do you need the underlying text. This is what you ask for. But why do you need that?

Comment: why is it relevant "why i need that".